# Unity: сигнал при изменении Toggle

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть стандартный ToggleGroup. В нём много Toggle-ов, а один из них выбран.

---

*Как я могу понять был ли изменён выбранный Toggle в ToggleGroup-е?*

Comment: через событие OnValueChanged отдельных Toggle можно

Comment: @trollingchar мне нужно проверять все Toggle-ы?

Comment: Ну не проверять конечно, а обрабатывать событие с них. Можно конечно еще посмотреть документацию по ToggleGroup но там аналогичного события я что-то не нашел https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.ToggleGroup.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Этот вопрос я задал попозже в другом формате.
Ответ на этот вопрос можете найти [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1008692/unity-%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-togglegroup)!