# Unity: Событие для ToggleGroup

Tags: unity3d, события

Я когда то [спрашивал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1006379/unity-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-toggle) про сигнал при изменении Toggle из ToggleGroup. Мне ответили, что надо писать событие. Как писать событие я посмотрел [в документации](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Events.UnityEvent.html) Unity, но мягко сказать не понял.

---

И так в чём же мой вопрос.
Я вас прошу сделать хотя бы один из этих пунктов.

- Дать мне такие источники, где человек, который ни разу не работал с событиями, сможет понять как правильно и корректно их писать.
- Писать основную часть кода (если не сложно с комментариями).

И я хочу чтобы вы знали, что я не хочу, чтобы вы делали работу вместо меня. Я хочу чтобы вы мне подсказали правильный путь. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала небольшое объяснение, что такое событие. Вот есть у нас, к примеру, кнопка. И кнопка иногда будет нажиматься. Мы могли бы захардкодить ей функцию нажатия, чтобы она показывала какое-то меню, но это сделало бы ее неуниверсальной, потому что больше ничего она делать не будет.

А можно объявить, что нажатие кнопки - это событие, за которым можно следить и обрабатывать обработчиками, когда оно происходит. Кнопка решает, когда событие произойдет, а другие классы подписывают на него обработчики, и эти обработчики вызываются в тот момент, когда оно происходит.

---

У `Toggle` определено событие `onValueChanged`, поэтому вам нужно будет подписать на него обработчик. Я покажу скрипт сразу для всей задачи:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;


public class NewBehaviourScript1 : MonoBehaviour {

    private void Awake () {
        var toggles = GetComponentsInChildren <Toggle> ();
        foreach (var t in toggles) {
            var toggle = t;
            // IDE говорит что напрямую переменную цикла foreach передавать в замыкание нехорошо
            // типа поведение в разных версиях компилятора отличается
            t.onValueChanged.AddListener (on => { if (on) Handle (toggle); });
        }
    }


    private void Handle (Toggle toggle) {
        Debug.Log (toggle.name);
    }

}
```

Цепляем его на объект с `ToggleGroup`. При инициализации он вешает обработчики на все дочерние `Toggle`. В принципе вы можете не делать `Handle` отдельным методом, а писать код прямо в лямбда-выражении (это вон та безымянная функция: `on => {...}`).

Мы нигде не чистим обработчики, потому что время жизни отдельных `Toggle` не превышает время жизни объекта с нашим скриптом, они уничтожатся вместе с ним.

---

Чисто ради интереса, как отписывать обработчики:

`t.onValueChanged.RemoveListener(...);`

Однако, если вы напишете, как вам кажется, ту же самую лямбду, ничего не удалится, потому что это не та же самая лямбда. Сохраняйте ее в переменную тогда. С обычными методами вроде бы такой проблемы нет.

Ну и еще можно удалить ВСЕ обработчики:

`t.onValueChanged.RemoveAllListeners();`

Comment: Спасибо большое. Но у меня остались 2 вопроса. 1. Почему в Awake() а не в Start(). 2.Что этот (http://prntscr.com/omwhi0) знак делает?

Comment: @Alt_F4 1. можно и в Start в принципе, просто Awake раньше выполняется и не зависит от того включен скрипт или нет. 2. Этот знак - часть синтаксиса [лямбда-выражения](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions).