# Как правильно сделать систему очков в Unity? Я столкнулся с данной проблемой

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-ui

Я столкнулся с проблемой по созданию системы очков. Делал их в Update(), а также создал GameManager, т.к. взаимодействую ещё с другим сценами. Столкнулся с тем, что очки очень быстро прибавляются. Очки должны прибавляться один раз, а не бесконечность, т.е. если ответ правильный, то плюс 2.8 очка. Я новичок и хотел бы попросить помощи. Окажите мне помощь, пожалуйста.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

 public class Excersice12 : MonoBehaviour
 {
private GameObject Manager;

public Dropdown dropdown1;

public Dropdown dropdown2;

public Dropdown dropdown3;

public Dropdown dropdown4;

public Dropdown dropdown5;

public Dropdown dropdown6;

public Dropdown dropdown7;

public Dropdown dropdown8;

void Start()
{
    Manager = GameObject.Find("GameManager").gameObject;

    dropdown1.GetComponent<Dropdown>().value = 0;

    dropdown2.GetComponent<Dropdown>().value = 0;

    dropdown3.GetComponent<Dropdown>().value = 0;

    dropdown4.GetComponent<Dropdown>().value = 0;

    dropdown5.GetComponent<Dropdown>().value = 0;

    dropdown6.GetComponent<Dropdown>().value = 0;

    dropdown7.GetComponent<Dropdown>().value = 0;

    dropdown8.GetComponent<Dropdown>().value = 0;
}

void Update()
{
    int menuIndex1 = dropdown1.GetComponent<Dropdown>().value;
    if (menuIndex1 == 0 || menuIndex1 == 1 || menuIndex1 == 2 || menuIndex1 == 3)
    {
       // Manager.GetComponent<GameManager>().score = Manager.GetComponent<GameManager>().score - 1;
    }
    else if (menuIndex1 == 4)
    {
        Manager.GetComponent<GameManager>().score = Manager.GetComponent<GameManager>().score + 2.8;
    }

    int menuIndex2 = dropdown2.GetComponent<Dropdown>().value;
    if (menuIndex2 == 0 || menuIndex2 == 1 || menuIndex2 == 3 || menuIndex2 == 4)
    {
       // Manager.GetComponent<GameManager>().score = Manager.GetComponent<GameManager>().score - 1;
    }
    else if (menuIndex2 == 2)
    {
        Manager.GetComponent<GameManager>().score = Manager.GetComponent<GameManager>().score + 2.8;
    }

    int menuIndex3 = dropdown3.GetComponent<Dropdown>().value;
    if (menuIndex3 == 0 || menuIndex3 == 1 || menuIndex3 == 2 || menuIndex3 == 4)
    {
       // Manager.GetComponent<GameManager>().score = Manager.GetComponent<GameManager>().score - 1;
    }
    else if (menuIndex3 == 4)
    {
        Manager.GetComponent<GameManager>().score = Manager.GetComponent<GameManager>().score + 2.8;
    }

    int menuIndex4 = dropdown4.GetComponent<Dropdown>().value;
    if (menuIndex4 == 0 || menuIndex4 == 1 || menuIndex4 == 3 || menuIndex4 == 4)
    {
       // Manager.GetComponent<GameManager>().score = Manager.GetComponent<GameManager>().score - 1;
    }
    else if (menuIndex4 == 2)
    {
        Manager.GetComponent<GameManager>().score = Manager.GetComponent<GameManager>().score + 2.8;
    }

    int menuIndex5 = dropdown5.GetComponent<Dropdown>().value;
    if (menuIndex5 == 0 || menuIndex5 == 1 || menuIndex5 == 2 || menuIndex5 == 3)
    {
       // Manager.GetComponent<GameManager>().score = Manager.GetComponent<GameManager>().score - 1;
    }
    else if (menuIndex5 == 4)
    {
        Manager.GetComponent<GameManager>().score = Manager.GetComponent<GameManager>().score + 2.8;
    }

    int menuIndex6 = dropdown6.GetComponent<Dropdown>().value;
    if (menuIndex6 == 0 || menuIndex6 == 1 || menuIndex6 == 2 || menuIndex6 == 4)
    {
       // Manager.GetComponent<GameManager>().score = Manager.GetComponent<GameManager>().score - 1;
    }
    else if (menuIndex6 == 3)
    {
        Manager.GetComponent<GameManager>().score = Manager.GetComponent<GameManager>().score + 2.8;
    }

    int menuIndex7 = dropdown7.GetComponent<Dropdown>().value;
    if (menuIndex7 == 0 || menuIndex7 == 1 || menuIndex7 == 2 || menuIndex7 == 4)
    {
       // Manager.GetComponent<GameManager>().score = Manager.GetComponent<GameManager>().score - 1;
    }
    else if (menuIndex7 == 3)
    {
        Manager.GetComponent<GameManager>().score = Manager.GetComponent<GameManager>().score + 2.8;
    }

    int menuIndex8 = dropdown8.GetComponent<Dropdown>().value;
    if (menuIndex8 == 0 || menuIndex8 == 1 || menuIndex8 == 3 || menuIndex8 == 4)
    {
       // Manager.GetComponent<GameManager>().score = Manager.GetComponent<GameManager>().score - 1;
    }
    else if (menuIndex8 == 2)
    {
        Manager.GetComponent<GameManager>().score = Manager.GetComponent<GameManager>().score + 2.8;
    }

    /*if (0 > Manager.GetComponent<GameManager>().score)
    {
        Manager.GetComponent<GameManager>().score = 0;
    }*/
   }
}
```

Comment: А как быстро они должны прибавляться? Чего конкретно вы хотите?

Comment: и несколько советов по коду: вместо кучи переменных используйте массив, и работайте с ним циклом, также не делайте много вызовов GetComponent если знаете что это один и тот же компонент, первым вызовом сохраните в переменную и с ней работайте дальше

Comment: trollingchar, очки должны прибавляться один раз, а не бесконечность, т.е. если ответ правильный, то плюс 2.8 очка.

Comment: тогда вам в апдейте не надо прибавлять очки, прибавляйте только когда пользователь примет ответ один раз, апдейт он каждый кадр вызывается

Comment: trollingchar, извините, что я настолько туго понимаю, но а где можно прибавлять очки тогда? В Start() или Awake()?

Comment: А как у вас ответ принимается? Кнопка какая-то есть?

Comment: trollingchar, логика у меня такова, что пользователь выбирает определённый ответ в DropdownMenu и идёт проверка в Update() (в моём случае, что является не правильным), потому что по-другому я не понимаю, пока что, как. И после того, как пользователь выбрал правильный ответ или наоборот, идёт подсчёт очков и вот они плюсуются бесконечно.

Comment: У `Dropdown` есть событие `onValueChanged`. Его вам и нужно использовать. [Здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1008894/319552) я только что рассказал как работать с событиями.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Честно сказать сложно понять что вы писали там в коде. Я его так понял.
У вас есть Dropdown который будет что то типа варианты ответов, так? И вы хотите чтобы если пользователь выбрал один из них то получил ответ либо правильно (+2.8 очков) либо нет. Крайне не советую в этом использовать Dropdown (используйте Toggle с компонентом ToggleGroup) но если именно так задан ваш вопрос, чтож...

```cs
float score;
public Dropdown Answers;
//Тут через инспектор вам надо подключить Dropdown

private void Start()
{
    //Тот что снизу называется слушатель. Он проверяет был ли изменён значение(value) в Dropdown-е
    Anwsers.onValueChanged.AddListener(delegate
    {
        if(Answers.value == 2) //В место 2 должен быть цифра правильного ответа
        {
            Debug.Log("That's right!");
            score += 2.8f;
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Эх");
        }
    });
}
```

---

Но если будете слушать меня и использовать ToggleGroup то вам повезло, потому  что на вопрос "Как писать событие для ToggleGroup" уже есть [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1008692/unity-%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-togglegroup/1008894#1008894).