# Как реализовать событие onValueChaged c Dropdown в Unity?

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-ui

Я столкнулся с проблемой, что после того, как получил ответ на [свой предыдущий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1008839/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%be%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b2-unity-%d0%af-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%81-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b9), мне ответили, что надо сделать событие `onValueChanged` с `Dropdown`. Но я не понимаю как. Прошу помощи, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так добавляйте событие onValueChanged

```cs
public Dropdown Example;

private void Start()
{
    Example.onValueChanged.AddListener(delegate
    {
    //Ваша функция если значение Dropdown изменился
    });
}
```